# How to set margin to StackPanel childrens

Tags: wpf

How to set `Margin` to the `StackPanel`  childrens depends up on the `StackPanel` Orientation, for example Orientatioin is horizontal then set margin 0,0,10,0 or orientation is Vertical then set margin 0,10,0,0. 
I try to find any idea but till now i not find anything, can you help me?

Thanks

Edit:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Q" />
        <Button Content="W" />
        <Button Content="E" />
        <Button Content="R" />
        <Button Content="T" />
        <Button Content="Y" />
        <Button Content="U" />
        <Button Content="I" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Do you want to set these margins,dynamically?

Comment: yes, i want to set dynamically

Comment: ok,how will you  create the stackpanels,using `xaml` code or by programmatically?

Comment: I edited the question. Please visit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
 <StackPanel Name="stack" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,10"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=stack, Path=Orientation}" Value="Horizontal">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,10,0" />                            
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Content="Q" />
    <Button Content="W" />
    <Button Content="E" />
    <Button Content="R" />
    <Button Content="T" />
    <Button Content="Y" />
    <Button Content="U" />
    <Button Content="I" />
</StackPanel>
```